# How to reflect the added entries on my UITableView?

Tags: iphone, uitableview, core-data, ios5, storyboard

I am using core data along with storyboards. I have 1 `UITableView` and 1 `UIViewController`. When I add entires to my entity it gets added in my context(database) but is not reflected in the table view when I go back. I have to run my app again and hen I can see my added entry. This is how I add new objects:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    myAppDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    self.managedObjectContext = myAppDelegate.sharedManagedObjectContext;

    NSFetchRequest *personListRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];

    NSEntityDescription *personEntity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Person" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];

    [personListRequest setEntity:personEntity];

    NSError *personListRequestError;

    NSArray *personsList = [self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:personListRequest error:&personListRequestError];


    for(Person *thisPerson in personsList ) {
        NSLog(@"First name is %@", thisPerson.firstName);
        NSLog(@"First name is %@", thisPerson.lastName);
    }    
    NSLog(@"the contents of array are %@",personsList);
    personArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:personsList];
}
```

I want my entries to be updated in my table when I add them, I don't want to run my app again to see them.

Comment: call this at the bottom of viewDidLoad:[self.tableview reloadData].

Comment: i jus dont want to reload the data it has to reload with the fresh database rite can anyone gimme a sample im new to this.. thanks

Answer (score 1):

You use a fetched results controller to efficiently manage the results returned from a Core Data fetch request to provide data for a UITableView object.

While table views can be used in several ways, this object is primarily intended to assist you with a master list view. UITableView expects its data source to provide cells as an array of sections made up of rows. You configure an instance of this class using a fetch request that specifies the entity, an array containing at least one sort ordering, and optionally a filter predicate. NSFetchedResultsController efficiently analyzes the result of the fetch request and computes all the information about sections in the result set, and for the index. for more details [apple doc](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreData/Reference/NSFetchedResultsController_Class/Reference/Reference.html) and [other sample](http://www.raywenderlich.com/999/core-data-tutorial-how-to-use-nsfetchedresultscontroller)

Answer (score 0):

you need to tell the tableview to reload it's data:

```
[tableView reloadData];
```